# Create SegmentControl based on UserControl in C# for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I'm quite new for developing on windows phone.  Currently I want to make a `segment control`.  It's just like this in iOS:

[image]

What I do is as below.
1 Create a class based on usercontrol:

```
public partial class WCCSegmentControl : UserControl
```

2 Create a property for this class to indicate the number of the buttons for this segment control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonsCount", typeof(int), typeof(WCCSegmentControl), new PropertyMetadata(ButtonsCountChanged));
```

3 I create the function `ButtonsCountChanged`:

```
private static void ButtonsCountChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WCCSegmentControl)d).ButtonsCount = (int)e.NewValue;
}
```

4 I also have this set and get:

```
public int ButtonsCount
{
    get
    {
        return (int)GetValue(ButtonsCountProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        SetValue(ButtonsCountProperty, value);

    }
}
```

5 in the contructor, I do this:

```
public WCCSegmentControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    buttons = new List<Button>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ButtonsCount; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Height = 64;
        button.Width = 64;
        buttons.Add(button);
        stackPanelSegmentControlRoot.Children.Add(button);
    } 
}
```

6 in the XAML, I set the `ButtonsCount` property to 2, but I debug it and find that in the constructor, the `ButtonsCount` is always 0.

Anybody knows where's wrong in my code?
Thank you!

Comment: Delete all your code. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). And please, don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in XAML based technologies. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore I do want to figure it out where's wrong.  do you have any idea?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, everything in your code is wrong. This is not how you define an Item-based UI in XAML based technologies, please read the above linked ItemsControl tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a template for RadioButton

Exemple:

```
    <Grid
        Background="{StaticResource SegmentedControlColor2}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource SegmentedControlColor1 }"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        x:Name="MainGrid">


        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainGrid">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SegmentedControlColor1}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SegmentedControlColor2}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>

        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">

        </Grid>

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Foreground="{StaticResource SegmentedControlColor1}"
                          TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>

</ControlTemplate>
```

and put RadioButtons into ItemsControl (on your page).

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <RadioButton    Height="40" Content="Test 4" Checked="radio_Checked" Template="{StaticResource SegmentedControl}"  BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"/>
                <RadioButton    Height="40" Content="Test 4" Checked="radio_Checked" Template="{StaticResource SegmentedControl}"  BorderThickness="1"/>
                <RadioButton    Height="40" Content="Test 4" Checked="radio_Checked" Template="{StaticResource SegmentedControl}"  BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"/>
</ItemsControl>
```